# parsing HTML with spark

Tags: html, scala, html-parsing, apache-spark

I want to do the following thing:

1. load html sources from a csv file
2. write a bunch of functions that will extract some features from the html source. I used to do it in Python when I would employ BeautifulSoup to do the job. Now I am using spark and write my code in scala. I've been looking for some good example how to do it, but haven't found much.

I would appreciate some exhaustive response how to do it, but if not maybe you guys could at least answer one of the following questions for me:

1. I have some flexibility over the input data format but I thought csv would be the simples. Then I have to escape the delimiter though. How do I do it when I read the file using sparkContext.textFile?
2. What library/functions to use to build the DOM tree for each source (which will be in one row of my RDD). Is  using some XML parser alright? I'm not sure if I understand how HTML parsers are different from the XML ones. I thought HTML was a subset of XML but I've read it is not quite true and that the XML parsers are not really well suited for html (because HTML is more lenient). So how to parse HTML?

Hints appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

For the parsing part of your question, I would suggest [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) : an HTML parser written in Java. It's an equivalent to BeautifulSoup.